# Is it possible for a Laravel API to consume a Node API and this Node API call that same Laravel API in a request?

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, laravel

I'll explain what's happening. I have a client (front-end) that consumes an endpoint in a Laravel API, this endpoint will communicate with an API in Node.js and this Node.js API will consume the Laravel API (all this happening in a single request), the problem is that this is not working, the request is in "infinite loop" and it takes a lot to parse the response, when it appears it generates an error:

```
TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript structures that include circular references can't be serialized. There is not much you can do about that except specifying a custom serializer function that detects and cleans up circular references.